# Using the TypeScript compiler API how can I get the actual, inferred type parameters for a call?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I would like to use the TypeScript compiler API to get information about inferred types.

For example, in

```
// Two generic functions
function identity<T>(x: T): T { return x }
function copy<U>(x: Array<U>): Array<U> { return [...x] }

// Call to identity should have <T> bound to <Array<String>>
// based on context type.
let arr: Array<String> = identity([]);
// Call to identity should have <T> bound to <Array<String>>
// based on parameter type.
identity(arr);

// Calls to copy have parameters inferred like the two calls
// to identity, but <U> binds to <String>, not <Array<String>>.
let arrCopy: Array<String> = copy([]);
copy(arrCopy);
```

How can I get the bindings for type parameters like `<T>` and `<U>` for *CallExpression* nodes?

Is there a general way to get a computed type for a node?  I see *TypeChecker.getTypeOfSymbol*, but most nodes, AFAICT, do not have symbols associated?

---

After looking at the above code in [ts-ast-viewer.com](https://ts-ast-viewer.com/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAJgUzLKBPAPAFQD4AKADwC5F8BKS-RAb0QCc0oRmlTEBfAKD4QANgEMAzmMQBhAoUZ9EixBSqIAPojAghQgNwKlAB2YwAbiKhpEOQ2nwiA5pQBEU54gC8iV8-1LEEAhiUMwg0HDMZHTqmtpCnrE61IzWABYwYgB03F6kurx8-HxCbIgilDIAyiEwYA5yXqgYWNjEYGgA7tLE1NS6QA) it looks like TS treats `[]` as having type `Array<never>` which seems an odd choice if arrays are invariant.

But the below introduces an invariant `class C<T>` which does seem to propagate type parameter information from context to constructor call.

```
function identity<T>(x: T): T { return x }

class C<T> {
    x: T | null;
    private typeTag: "C" = "C";
    constructor(x: T | null = null) { this.x = x; }
}

let a: C<String> = identity(new C());
```

Comment: It looks like *TypeChecker*'s `getResolvedSignature(node: CallLikeExpression, candidatesOutArray?: Signature[], argumentCount?: number): Signature | undefined;` may be related.